# If $\int_0^1 |f|dx= (\int_0^1|f|^p dx)^{1/p}$ for some $p > 1$, then $f$ is constant.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

> If $\int_0^1 |f|dx= (\int_0^1|f|^p dx)^{1/p}$ for some $p > 1$, then $f$ is constant.

Since $\int _0 ^1 |f| dx = \int _\mathbb{R} fg dx $ where $g \mbox{ is characteristic function on } [0,1]$, I tried to use Holder inequality.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) indeed works.
$$ \|f\cdot 1\|_1 \color{red}{\leq} \|f\|_p \|1\|_q = \|f\|_p $$
where $\color{red}{\leq}$ holds as an equality iff $f=\lambda\cdot 1$ almost everywhere on $[0,1]$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, i.e. iff $f$ is almost everywhere constant on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Indeed, this is a correct restatement of the question, OP does want to show that given $p>1$, $\|f\|_1 = \|f\|_p \implies f$ is constant. But in general people want proofs...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: this **is** a proof. It is enough to recall in which cases Holder's inequality holds as an equality. That is pretty well known.